# Jquery hidden not working with css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one question about Jquery hidden fuction.

I have two different Demo from *codepen.io*

First **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/bNBXLw)** css animation will working. but `.wrap` is not to be hidden when i click second time `.note a`.

Second **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/myRbMR)** `.wrap` is hidden but not with animation. I want when i click `.note a` for close `.wrap` then `.wrap` going to be a hidden with css animation like first **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/bNBXLw)**.

Comment: so basically you want show and hide to be animated?

Comment: @CerlinBoss Yes it is true.

Comment: what animation you want?

Comment: @CerlinBoss you can see in first DEMO my CSS animation working on there. I want to that animation when `.wrap` hidden.

Comment: you mean the bounce effect of the circles?

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes it's true

Comment: so you want that bounce effect to come while showing and hiding the `wrap`?

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes but i couldn't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwaPQG)

is this what you wanted?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var circle = $('.circle');
    var wrap = $('.wrap');
    $(".note a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.wrap').is(':hidden') ? $('.wrap').show() : setTimeout(function(){$('.wrap').hide()},500);
        if (wrap.hasClass('bounceInUp')) {
            wrap.removeClass('bounceInUp').addClass('bounceOutDown');
        }
        else {
            wrap.addClass('animated bounceOutDown');
            wrap.removeClass('bounceOutDown').addClass('bounceInUp');
        }
        if (circle.hasClass('bounceInLeft')) {
            circle.removeClass('bounceInLeft').addClass('bounceOutRight');
        }
        else {
            $('.circle').addClass('animated bounceOutRight');
            circle.removeClass('bounceOutRight').addClass('bounceInLeft');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thants ok. so If you do not mind, I want to ask you something. How do I add a pupup?

Comment: popup where?. i am not sure what you are asking

Comment: can i show you example ? Like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/raBRxO) there is popup window. Can i add here like that popup ?

Comment: try some popup plugins online. it may help u

Answer (score 0):

Use a `setTimeout` function  http://codepen.io/akshay-7/pen/gbgYvx

```
 $('.wrap').is(':hidden') ? $('.wrap').show() : setTimeout(function(){
   $('.wrap').hide();
 },2000);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you check it if you click second time `.note a` then you see the six round will stay on there .